# SQL SELECT statement is not working?

Tags: python, sql, select

```
def showallres():
    sql = '''SELECT ResidentID,FirstName,SurName,Age,MDisability,History,Impairment,Money,Contact
    FROM tblResidentM'''
    results = run_sql2(sql)
    print(results)
    return results
```

for some reason it just prints 'None'? But it worked before. The table and all the fields are named correctly so I am unsure of what it is.

Here is the code for 'run_sql2'

```
def run_sql2(sql):
    db = db_connect()
    c = db.cursor() 
    c.execute(sql)
    results=c.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    c.close()
    db.close()
```

I am connecting to an online mysql database.

db_connect is as follows

```
def db_connect():
    try:
        db = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'user', password = 'pass', host = 'host', database = 'db', port = 'port')
        print('connected')
        return db
    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print(error)
```

Comment: Show the content of the `run_sql2` function.

Comment: Given any Error???

Comment: What database? What database connector? Did you troubleshoot by checking you are still connected to the database? What is `run_sql2()` doing? Where does it come from?

Comment: I have edited OP. :) No error messages or anything. It does connect to the database as it prints 'connected' and then prints results as 'none'.

Comment: And what does `db_connect()` look like? :P

Comment: you are not returning anything from run_sql2.  Also you don't want to close the cursor before fetching the data

Comment: Oh yeah... simple 'return results'

Answer (score 2):

Your function `run_sql2()` does not return anything,
in Python a function returns None by default, that's why `results` is None

```
def run_sql2(sql):
    db = db_connect()
    c = db.cursor() 
    c.execute(sql)
    results = c.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    c.close()
    db.close()
    return results  # <---- you must return the results
```

Comment: Yeah. Rookie error. :') Cheers.